# Find duplicates in array of hashes on specific keys

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hash, duplicates

I have an array of hashes (CSV rows, actually) and I need to find and keep all the rows that match two specific keys (user, section). Here is a sample of the data:

```
[
  { user: 1, role: "staff", section: 123 },
  { user: 2, role: "staff", section: 456 },
  { user: 3, role: "staff", section: 123 },
  { user: 1, role: "exec", section: 123 },
  { user: 2, role: "exec", section: 456 },
  { user: 3, role: "staff", section: 789 }
]
```

So what I would need to return is an array that contained only the rows where the same user/section combo appears more than once, like so:

```
[
  { user: 1, role: "staff", section: 123 },
  { user: 1, role: "exec", section: 123 },
  { user: 2, role: "staff", section: 456 },
  { user: 2, role: "exec", section: 456 }
]
```

The double loop solution I'm trying looks like this:

```
enrollments.each_with_index do |a, ai|
  enrollments.each_with_index do |b, bi|
    next if ai == bi

    duplicates << b if a[2] == b[2] && a[6] == b[6]
  end
end
```

but since the CSV is 145K rows it's taking *forever*.

How can I more efficiently get the output I need?

Comment: What are you using to read the CSV? `CSV.foreach` should read a line at a time which would be beneficial memory consumption wise. But you need to compare all the rows anyway. YOu can either do that all in memory or save to the database and have it to the uniqueness search.

Comment: I am reading the CSV into an array. So you're recommending to just do the comparison at read time? Like two nested `CSV.foreach` blocks?

Comment: Definitely not two `CSV.foreach` calls. See answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In terms of efficiency you might want to try this:

```
grouped = csv_arr.group_by{|row| [row[:user],row[:section]]}
filtered = grouped.values.select { |a| a.size > 1 }.flatten
```

The first statement groups the records by the `:user` and `:section` keys. the result is:

```
{[1, 123]=>[{:user=>1, :role=>"staff", :section=>123}, {:user=>1, :role=>"exec", :section=>123}],
 [2, 456]=>[{:user=>2, :role=>"staff", :section=>456}, {:user=>2, :role=>"exec", :section=>456}],
 [3, 123]=>[{:user=>3, :role=>"staff", :section=>123}],
 [3, 789]=>[{:user=>3, :role=>"staff", :section=>789}]}
```

The second statement only selects the values of the groups with more than one member and then it flattens the result to give you:

```
[{:user=>1, :role=>"staff", :section=>123},
 {:user=>1, :role=>"exec", :section=>123},
 {:user=>2, :role=>"staff", :section=>456},
 {:user=>2, :role=>"exec", :section=>456}]
```

This could improve the speed of your operation, but memory wise I can't say what the effect would be with a large input, because it would depend on your machine, resources and the size of file

Comment: This does exactly what I need _except_ I just found out the data I was provided has some garbage in it. Next task is to figure out how to clean it up so I can use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this check in memory you don't need a double loop, you can keep an array of unique values and check each new csv line against it:

```
found = []
unique_enrollments = []

CSV.foreach('/path/to/csv') do |row|
  # do whatever you're doing to parse this row into the hash you show in your question:
  # => { user: 1, role: "staff", section: 123 }
  # you might have to do `next if row.header_row?` if the first row is the header

  enrollment = parse_row_into_enrollment_hash(row)
  unique_tuple = [enrollment[:user], enrollment[:section]]

  unless found.include? unique_tuple
    found << unique_tuple
    unique_enrollments << enrollment
  end
end
```

Now you have `unique_enrollments`. With this approach you parse the CSV line by line so you're not keeping the whole thing in memory. Then building a smaller array of unique tuples made of the user and section with which you'll use for your uniqueness check and also building up the array of unique rows.

You can further optimize this by not saving the `unique_enrollments` in a big array but rather just building your Model and saving it to the db:

```
unless found.include? unique_tuple
  found << unique_tuple
  Enrollment.create enrollment
end
```

With the above tweak you'll be able to save on memory by not keeping a big array of enrollments. Although the drawback would be that if something blows up you won't be able to rollback. For example, had we done the former and kept an array of `unique_enrollments` at the end you can do:

```
Enrollment.transaction do
  unique_enrollments.each &:save!
end
```

And now you have the ability to rollback if any of those saves blow up. Also, wrapping a bunch of db calls in a single `transaction` is much faster. I'd go with this approach.

**Edit:** Using the array of `unique_enrollments` you can iterate over these at the end and create a new CSV:

```
CSV.open('path/to/new/csv') do |csv|
  csv << ['user', 'role', 'staff'] # write the header

  unique_enrollments.each do |enrollment|
    csv << enrollment.values # just the values not the keys
  end
end
```

Comment: There's no database. I'm just trying to get data I need out of a local CSV. I also think I caused a little confusion with my sample data. The data is coming in untouched, but I'm only comparing certain fields, and I want to store it untouched. Basically it's 1. load 2. perform check 3. output rows that meet check condition.

Comment: Oh that's fine, just save all the unique rows and use them to write back out to a new CSV.